# What is version support of Module created in DotnetNuke 7?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have created a Module(Portal). I am going to publish it. I just don't know which version it can support. The previous versions and future versions. I am just curious above this all specially in case of .DLLs.

Please suggest me.

Development system

1- Visual Studio 2015

2- DotnetNuke 7

[image]

DLLs
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will all depend on what version of the DotNetNuke.DLLs you compile your module against.

Typically if you compile against a version, say 07.00.01, the module will run on that version AND any NEWER version of DNN.

There are some cases where there are breaking changes for modules on upgrade of the DNN version, but they are pretty few and far between.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have edited my question and added SS of DLLs. Can you please let me know about support from SS? I am on Documentation Phase. It's bit crutial. Thank you.

Comment: I always compile against the DLLs I have in the BIN folder of the development environment. So whatever you have in the BIN folder is what you should worry about.